# Python True or False game prototype not working

Tags: python

I'm trying to do a little game in python.
Here's what I've got so far:

```
import time
name = raw_input("What is your name? ")
print "Hi,", name,"!"
time.sleep(1)
print "Let's start my game"
time.sleep(1)
q1 = None
while (q1 == "None"):
    qq1 = raw_input("Question")
    if (qq1 == "answer"):
        q1 = True
print "Game Over!"
```

This is what I get:

```
What is your name? nametest
Hi, nametest !
Let's start my game
Game Over!
>>>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You are missing an explanation to tell us what it is you are actually expecting it to do.

Answer (score 4):

It's because of the discrepancy between the lines

```
q1 = None
```

where you say that `q1` is the 
[*object* `None`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html#types.NoneType),

and the line

```
while (q1 == "None"):
```

where you check if it is the *string* `"none"`, which is entirely different.

---

Try changing them both to be the same, e.g.,

```
while q1 is None:
```

Answer (score 0):

You say `while (q1 == "None")`, but `q1` is never equal to the string `"None"`; it is equal to the *constant* `None`.  You could say `== None`, but using `is` is recommended:

```
while (q1 is None):
```

`is` should be used because `None` is a constant.  There may be things that claim equality with `None`, but only `None` is an instance of `NoneType`.

Answer (score 0):

`None` is not `"None"`, just using only one of them, it will work.

But using `False` is better:

```
q1 = False
while (q1 == False):
    qq1 = raw_input("Question")
    if (qq1 == "answer"):
        q1 = True
```